# (C++) Segmentation fault when link list head is assigned to another pointer of same structure

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

When I assign the link list head (of type pointer to struct) to another temporary head (of the same type), I get the segmentation error. Can someone please help me with this?

I am using below online compiler to run this code.
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

struct Node{
    int val;
    Node *next;
};

Node* newNode(int val){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->val = val;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    return newNode;
    
}

Node* addNode(Node *head, int val){
    
    if(head == nullptr){
        return newNode(val);
    }
    
    Node *current = head;
    while(current->next != nullptr){
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    current->next = newNode(val);
    return head;
    
}

void printList(Node *head){
    
    while(head){
        cout<<head->val<<" "; 
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    Node *head;
    head = addNode(head, 1);
    head = addNode(head, 2);
    head = addNode(head, 3);
    head = addNode(head, 4);
    head = addNode(head, 5);
    head = addNode(head, 6);
    head = addNode(head, 7);

    printList(head);
    
    //If comment out, then no segmentation fault 
    Node *head1 = head; //Segmentation fault
   
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't post the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code as formatted text in the question. Not some links to online compilers that are not even related to your question. Please also don't add unrelated language tags as this is considered spamming.

Comment: Your links don't work. Post the code in the question.

Comment: I have added the code now.

Answer (score 1):

In `main()`, change `Node *head;` to `Node *head = nullptr;`. Your code has *undefined behavior* when the 1st call to `addNode()` tries to evaluate an *uninitialized* pointer.

Everything else looks OK.

Comment: No need to edit, I was just adding something to that effect.